# Using javascript to call download file?

Tags: javascript

I need to use javascript to call a page that simply downloads a file.

ok, so i have this page (http://example.com/download.php?myfile.pdf for example) that when called, it echo's out the data and causes the browser to begin downloading the file.

I want to create a javascript that will call the page using something like XMLHttpRequest. (not using ajax or jquery)

Once I have the blob of data, I need to save it to the local computer using XPCOM. (this is for an extension for Firefox 45)

Can anyone show me some example of how to do this?

Comment: Request the file and create a `Blob` representation of the response. You cannot force a file to be downloaded. The download of a file should occur in response to user action of accepting the offer for download.

Comment: AJAX _is_ "using something like `XMLHttpRequest`"...

Comment: Example code would be very helpful.